# What is the role of people with physical disabilities?

Tags: handicap-disabled-impair, beauty

The Torah says that Kohanim with physical defects may not offer sacrifices:

> The Lord spoke further to Moses: Speak to Aaron and say: No man of your offspring throughout the ages who has a defect shall be qualified to offer...  food...  No one at all who has a defect shall be qualified: no man who is blind, or lame, or has a limb too short or too long; who has a broken leg or a broken arm; or who is a hunchback, or a dwarf, or who has a growth in his eye, or who has a boil-scar, or scurvy, or crushed testes.  No man among the offspring of Aaron the priest who has a defect shall be qualified to offer the Lord’s offering by fire.  [Lev. 21:16-21]

To modern ears, this may sound unfair, but I have heard it said that it simply means that Kohanim with deformities are chosen for something else.  Indeed, the Talmud says that ugly people make the best scholars.  [Taanit 7a-b and Nedarim 50b]  It also does not countenance downgrading ugly people. [Taanit 20b]

Where can I find more detailed discussions of how that passage in Leviticus has a positive twist?

Comment: Ii it less fair that Israelites can't offer sacrifices?

Comment: My question is focused only on physical defects -- "ugliness".

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi You changed from disabilities to defects